# change constant

Tags: constants, reinterpret-cast

Please explain to me why I can not change constant by using next?

```
const int i = 10;
int * p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&i);
```

Comment: A constat is ... constant! Why would you change it?

Comment: I just wanna know a way to come over it.. but question was not how to do it, I asked Why cannot go this way.. Thx for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `const_cast` to cast away constness, `const_cast` is specifically for this case.

Comment: With that caveat that casting away const and using the result in a non-const way invokes UB if the original object was declared as const.

Answer (score 0):

const means constant, as in you can't change it.
You could do a `int nonconst_i = const_cast<int>(i);` then use nonconst_i

Comment: Well, in your example, it should be `int* p = const_cast<int*>(&i);` I believe.